# Win10 BLE desktop application IAsyncOperation as collection

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy, iasyncoperation

I am working on upgrading desktop app to run on windows 10 with BLE support. I modified the app to target to corresponding windows version as described in [this question (How can I reference the Windows 8 Runtime in console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843102/how-can-i-reference-the-windows-8-runtime-specifically-ble-api-in-a-console-ap). Now trying to do step by step as in [this example (Using BLE GATT services with Windows 10)](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=167). First of all I need run ble scan as follows:

```
var devices = deviceInformation.FindAllAsync(GattDeviceService.GetDeviceSelectorFromUuid(GattServiceUuids.HeartRate));
if (devices != null)
{
   foreach (DeviceInformation device in devices)
   {
       // add device into your UI here
   }
}
```

But on compilation i get error related to foreach loop, here is the error:

> Error CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
>   'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation'
>   because
>   'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation'
>   does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: You must **await** methods whose name ends in "Async".

Comment: @Hans Passsant thanks, this is helpful. I added **async** and **await** keywords, also used suggestions from [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428446/storagefile-async-usage-in-a-non-metro-application/19731831#19731831) and seems error disappeared